# Magento 2: "There has been an error processing your request"

Tags: magento2, nginx, php-7

I installed Magento 2.1 on my Centos 7 server, running Nginx 1.10.1, MariaDB 10.1 and PHP7 with SSL. In theory, everything installed just fine and after the installation I got no errors what-so-ever, and "systemctl status nginx" and "systemctl status php-fpm" both show that they should be working fine. But when I try to access my site in web browser, I get following:

> "There has been an error processing your request
>
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 886472238215"

So I went to "usr/share/nginx/magento2/var/report" and opened that log number 886472238215:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:226:"Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_au56sith2u5dloibaakd9c3q06, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22";i:1;s:6680:"#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'SessionHandler:...', '/usr/share/ngin...', 22, Array)
#1 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php(22): SessionHandler->read('au56sith2u5dloi...')
#2 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php(93): Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler\Native->read('au56sith2u5dloi...')
#3 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler->read('au56sith2u5dloi...')
#4 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(189): session_start()
#5 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start()
#6 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php(52): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->___callPlugins('start', Array, Array)
#7 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(130): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->start()
#8 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Validator), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Storage), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\App\State))
#9 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Validator), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Storage), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\App\State))
#10 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#11 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#12 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Proxy.php(84): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#13 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Proxy.php(207): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Proxy->_getSubject()
#14 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Url.php(942): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Proxy->getSessionIdForHost('https://www......')
#15 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Url.php(1096): Magento\Framework\Url->_prepareSessionUrl('https://www......')
#16 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(78): Magento\Framework\Url->getRedirectUrl('https://www.......')
#17 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#19 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#22 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#25 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#28 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#30 /usr/share/nginx/magento2/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#31 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

And here is the content of /usr/share/nginx/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler;

/**
 * Php native session save handler
 */
class Native extends \SessionHandler
{
    /**
     * Workaround for php7 session_regenerate_id error
     * @see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71187
     *
     * @param string $sessionId
     * @return string
     */
    public function read($sessionId)
    {
        return (string)parent::read($sessionId);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem might be?

Answer (score 4):

I have faced same issue On my shared server.

So what I did is open my `env.php` file and

find

```
 array (
  'save' => 'files',
),
```

and replace with (I created session folder in var directory of my magento)

```
array (
  'save' => 'files',
  'save_path' => 'var/session',
),
```

Comment: For me `array (
  'save' => 'files',
  'save_path' => '/tmp',
),`

Answer (score 2):

Add below session code php.ini file at end of file

```
session.save_handler = files
;session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

to

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "var/www/magento2/var/session"
```

Edited php.env file:

```
'session' =>
     array (
    'save' => 'files',
   ),
```

to

```
'session' =>
     array (
    'save' => 'files',
    'save_path' => '/var/www/magento2/var/session',
   ),
```

Let me know if you still got an issue.

Answer (score 1):

php package has some `pre|post` installation scenario in its `specfile`, and one of commands is:

```
......
%dir %attr(0770, root, apache) "/var/lib/php/session"
......
```

so im afraid that probably all your changes will be overwritten on the next php upgrade. no need to chmod or change owner anyway.

you have one option to properly fix it:

open your php-fpm pool config file `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`
and change these lines at the bottom:

```
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path]    = /path/to/magento/var/session
```

or remove them and use `redis` or `memcached`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that user of php-fpm process do not have write access to /var/lib/php/session/* files. Please find out username and user group and change access on folder 
like

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/php/
```

or if it developer environment you can simple (**but not secure**) add access for all

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/lib/php/
```

Comment: This could cause issues, depending on how you set up your server. All users that need write access to the Magento file system should share the same *group* and you should not set world-writable permissions. Look at our [file system ownership and permissions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html) and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: @SteveJohnson So I went to see my "www.conf" -file and checked out the user, and it was nginx. I used following command:  

> sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/ 

This fixed the "There has been an error processing your request" -problem, but now the site is giving me "404 Not Found" on every single page and I can see a stripped-down version of my site. I have added a link to a picture, to better demonstrate the current problem:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96826437/Errors/404_Not_Found.png

Comment: you need to delete cache and deploy static content

Comment: still getting error any help thanks