# Magento 2 Session issue

Tags: magento2, session, php-7

I have moved my Magento code base to another folder and I have upgraded the php version to **php7**. Now I am facing the following error.

> SessionHandler::read(): Session data file is not created by your uid
>   Warning: SessionHandler::write(): Session data file is not created by
>   your uid in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php on line
>   105
>
> Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (user). Please verify
>   that the current setting of session.save_path is correct
>   (/var/www/html/var/session/) in Unknown on line 0

Help me to fix this

Comment: go through this link if you find your answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124199/magento-2-there-has-been-an-error-processing-your-request

Comment: No its not working

Comment: @KrishnanDaiva, delete your cookies and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to destroy your session. You can do this by deleting your cookies.

Also make sure that the owner and group of all your files and folders is set correctly.

Go to your magento root and execute `chown -R user:webgroup *` e.g. `chown -R magento:www *`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by removing var / cache & var / session